# Bazel Rule to get all targets

Tags: bazel, target, rules

New to Bazel. Looking to see if there is a way to create a Bazel rule that allows me to get a list of all targets and then feed that data into a kotlin file or something like that.

I was able to run `bazel query //... --export xml > temp.xml` this gives me all the targets and their build files info but I would like to retrieve this info using a bazel rule, any ideas of how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The closest thing to this in Bazel is a [genquery](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/general.html#genquery), though it's worth noting that there are some caveats to this approach as mentioned in the docs;

> In order to keep the build consistent, the query is allowed only to visit the transitive closure of the targets specified in the scope attribute. Queries violating this rule will fail during execution if strict is unspecified or true (if strict is false, the out of scope targets will simply be skipped with a warning). The easiest way to make sure this does not happen is to mention the same labels in the scope as in the query expression.

If you are happy to blow past the warnings around 'build consistency' it might be possible to achieve this using a similar approach to the [buildifier](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/buildifier/README.md) rules, where you would determine the path of the workspace and run Bazel query as a subprocess of Bazel. Personally, I wouldn't recommend this and instead would suggest that you just use the output of `bazel query` directly.